# Get value of a variable in one component to another component using ngmodel

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

I have two components **first** and **second**. From the second component, I am calling the first component. In the first component, I have a `matslider` module and I want to get that slider **on/off** status to my second component `ts` file. So I am getting that value in first, but don't know how to pass that to the second component.

**first.component.html**

```
<div>
<mat-slide-toggle class="toggles" 
(change)="OnToggle($event) 
[(ngModel)]="selected">Toggle</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

**first.component.ts**

```
@Input() selected=false;
public OnToggle(event)
{
  this.selected = event.selected;
}
```

**second.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
<app-first> </app-first>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use subject/behaviorSubject to pass

Comment: What is the parent component? First or second? Or are these components are siblings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use an output event in the first component and bind to it in the second component.

here it is example:

**First Component:**

```
  @Output() selectedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  public OnToggle(event) {
  this.selected = event.selected;
  this.selectedChange.emit(this.selected);
```

}

**SecondComponent**:

```
<app-first (selectedChange)="onSelectedChange($event)"></app-first>


public onSelectedChange(selected: boolean) {
  console.log(selected);
}
```

Comment: thanks Behram ..it worked..can we do the same using ngModel?

Comment: Yes, you can also use the ngModel directive to pass the value of the mat-slide-toggle from the first component to the second component.

Comment: how can we use by ngmodel...I tried but i'm not getting val in the other component.....                                  
 <mat-slide-toggle class="toggles" 
(change)="OnToggle($event) 
(ngModel)="selectedChange">Toggle</mat-slide-toggle>

Comment: try like this <div>
  <mat-slide-toggle class="toggles" [(ngModel)]="selected">Toggle</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <app-first [(selected)]="toggleStatus"></app-first>
</div>

export class SecondComponent {
  public toggleStatus: boolean;
}